# Scraping commented Data (<!-- -->) i.e. data inside them using jsoup library

Tags: java, jsoup

I was trying to scrape data from a website but I found that a certain piece of code from where I want to get some data is commented in the page's HTML i.e. it is lying inside these comment tag. 
Is it possible to get this data and if yes what's the effective way to do so.
Moreover, a similar piece of text is used in the page as that inside those comments.
Below is the piece of html code :

```
    <!--<div class="contact-price clearfix">
                        <h3>Contact For Price</h3>
                        <div class="user-online clearfix">
                            <div class="user-status">
                                <div class="status-active"></div>

                            </div>
                            <a href="#">View Complete Profile</a>
                        </div>

                        <div class="user-contact">
                            <button class="btn-default btn-primary" onclick="checkonline(305654806,event,246)">Chat Now</button>
                            <p class="call-number">
                                <i class="icon-phone"></i>
                                +91 0000000000
                                <span class="verifi"></span>
                            </p>
                            <a href="#" class="message"><i class="icon-messages"></i> Send free SMS</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
    -->


    <div class="contact-price clearfix">
        <h3> </h3>
        <div class="user-online clearfix">
            <div class="user-status">
                <div class="status-active"></div>
                    laser07
            </div>
            <a href="com/userProfile?uId=BWYAYgc0U2VTYlJiAWcFaFE1">View Complete Profile</a>
        </div>
        <div class="user-contact clearfix ">
            <button class="btn btn-default" onclick="checkonline(305654806,event,246)">Chat Now</button>
        </div>
        <div class="user-contact user-details clearfix">
            <div class="clearfix phn-email">
                <p class="call-number">
                    <i class="icon-mobile-phones"></i>
                     XXXXXXXXXX00
                    <span class="verify"></span>
                </p>
                <p class="call-number">
                    <i class="icon-email"></i>
                    xxxxxxxx@gmail.com
                </p>
            </div>
            <button  id ="reCaptchaGetContactDetails" class="btn btn-primary g-recaptcha  contact-details " >Contact</button>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I want to scrape the data from the upper part of the code, i.e one in between those comment tag. Say I want that contact number 0000000 inside p tag. How will I get that as I'm getting a null pointer each time I run my code which is :

```
Element elementphone = doc.select("div.contact-price").first().select("div.user-contact").first().select("p.call-number").first();

            Phone = elementphone.text();
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to get the comments in a html page while scraping?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48849183/how-to-get-the-comments-in-a-html-page-while-scraping)

Comment: The solution to that question is by BeautifulSoup Python. Whereas I'm using Java with JSoup Library

Comment: If you are sure that html in comments is valid you can simply remove them and then parse resulting html: `String html = doc.html();
  html = html.replaceAll("<!--", "").replaceAll("-->", "");
  doc = Jsoup.parse(html);`

Comment: worked for me.. thanku @Luk . But in case the html is not valid what should I do.?

Comment: Jsoup can handle some kinds of invalidity. If your html cannot be parsed by Jsoup you can either manipulate html before parsing to make it work or you should consider parsing it by yourself as a simple string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are sure that html in comments is valid you can simply remove them and then parse resulting html:

```
String html = doc.html(); 
html = html.replaceAll("<!--", "").replaceAll("-->", ""); 
doc = Jsoup.parse(html);
```